# Toad Add/Insert and Delete records Button Disabled

Tags: oracle, button, toad, disabled-control

I'm using Toad 8.6 and when I try to add new records using the Schema Browser, Data tab, my 'insert record' is grayed out. So, I installed the 9.6 version and the same problem persists.

See the grayed out buttons in red in the picture.

[image]

I'm able to add records through the SQL insert statement at the SQL Editor of Toad.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the + button that displays at the top of the SQL results grid?

There is an "edit grid" button which you're supposed to click first to then enable changes to the data grid. Otherwise the results grid is read-only.

Comment: no, i'm talking about the + sign at the top of Schema browser , the one you use when you want to add a new row to your database.

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck Default to Read only query in Toad Option (View--Options- Data Grid --Data)

Answer (score 2):

If the rowid is selected, then insert/edit icons will be enabled. e.g.
`select rowid, t.* from table t`

Answer (score 1):

Options > Data > untick "Use Read-Only Queries" > click OK > Close the Schema Browser and open a new Schema Browser window to see the buttons enabled:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is your TOAD installed Read-Only?  The help files provide information about installing TOAD as a Read-Only application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the viewer, then you need to uncheck the read only selection to the far left of the viewer screen. You get to this by pulling down the menu to the right of the red button. Once unchecked the button will turn green.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate 'updatable' mode. You can click on the button given in the circle [updatable icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbH1b.png)